# Table sort by using textExtraction using data-sort-value attribute in td

Tags: jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Added the following td. The date value is coming as a format  **01 Aug 1990**. I want to sort that column. But it is not working. How can I properly set the data-sort-value so that it sort in correct way

```
<td data-sort-value="${info.offDate}" class="${someclass}">${info.offDate}</td>
```

I have the following javascript for sorting -

```
$(function() {

$("#infoListTable").tablesorter({

    textExtraction: function(node) {

        var attr = $(node).attr('data-sort-value');
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            return attr;
        }
        return $(node).text(); 
    },headers: {
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        6: { sorter:'otherDate' }

    } 

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The built-in parser for 'dd-mm-yyyy' doesn't understand month names. It is expecting all numerical values.

You can add your own parser. Since modern browsers are able to parse `new Date("dd MMM yyyy")`, the parser is very simple ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/10057/)):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: 'date-dd-MM-yyyy',
  is: function() {
    return false;
  },
  format: function(str) {
    var date = str ? new Date(str) : str;
    return date instanceof Date && isFinite(date) ? date.getTime() : str;
  },
  type: 'numeric'
});

$('table').tablesorter({
  headers: {
    6: { sorter: 'date-dd-MM-yyyy' }
  }
});
```

Additionally, the `textExtraction` method can be simplified to:

```
textExtraction: function(node) {
  return $(node).attr('data-sort-value') || $(node).text();
}
```

since the jQuery `.attr()` function will return an empty string if undefined instead of `false`.